# How to disable the whole page?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a field where a customer number is required. When the user leaves the field in the onblur event I need to run some code, in this case check if the given number is already in use. The problem is the codes needs some time to complete. For this short period the user should not be able to make any input. Also I'd like to display a gif.

Comment: You might want to revisit your UX. On blur is a not very visible UX concept.  You might want to hide the rest of the form and have a next button then use the standby and show the form thereafter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a genius snippet on XSnippets called "Standby Dialog" (https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control)
If you implement this on your page (preferably as custom control) you will get an overlay everytime a partial refresh happens. If you init a partial refresh when the user blurs the field you will get what you want.